# how to grep a word with only one single capital letter?

Tags: grep, letter

The txt file is :

```
bar
quux
kabe
Ass
sBo
CcdD
FGH
```

I would like to grep the words with **only one capital letter** in this example, but when I use "grep [A-Z]", it shows me all words with capital letters.

Could anyone find the "grep" solution here? My expected output is

```
Ass
sBo
```

Comment: Does "word" mean letters only? By default, "word" characters are letters, digit and the underscore. Please clarify - all your test inputs are all-letters, but is that true in your real data?

Comment: `awk -F[A-Z] NF==2`??

Comment: @oguzismail - is that a `grep` solution, as the OP requested?

Comment: @mathguy nah, that's why it's a comment

Comment: @mathguy Maybe the OP does not know other tools that could also be useful (not improbable for newcomers). And it's a standard utility, so why not mention it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a text file with each word on its own line.

You may use

```
grep '^[[:lower:]]*[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*$' file
```

See the [`grep` online demo](https://ideone.com/k6mFsZ).

The `^` matches the start of string (here, line since `grep` operates on a line by lin basis by default), then `[[:lower:]]*` matches 0 or more lowercase letters, then an `[[:upper:]]` pattern matches any uppercase letter, and then `[[:lower:]]*` matches 0+ lowercase letters and `$`  asserts the position at the end of string.

If you need to match a whole line with exactly one uppercase letter you may use

```
grep '^[^[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]*$' file
```

The only difference from the pattern above is the `[^[:upper:]]` bracket expression that matches any char but an uppercase letter. See [another `grep` online demo](https://ideone.com/IqCPUi).

To extract words with a single capital letter inside them you may use word boundaries, as shown in mathguy's answer. With GNU grep, you may also use

```
grep -o '\b[^[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]*\b' file
grep -o '\b[[:lower:]]*[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*\b' file
```

See [yet another `grep` online demo](https://ideone.com/DlqeFr).

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '\<[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*\>' my.txt
```

will match lines in the ASCII text file `my.txt` if they contain at least one word consisting entirely of ASCII letters, exactly one of which is upper case.